# EventToCommand in portable MvvmLight

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I'm developing an application for WP8, and I would like to share some ViewModels with a windows store version, so I created a portable library, installed the portable version of MvvmLight and moved the code there.

From what I see, if I use the portable version of MVVM in a portable library, I have to use the same version even in the Windows8 application.

Now I have to bind handle the tap event in a ListBox to the ViewModel, to navigate to another view, and looks like I have to use the EventToCommand behavior, but this behavior is in the `WP8.Extras` dll of the standard version of MvvmLight, and I cannot add to my project.

How can I solve this? There is some way to bind an event to a ViewModel compatible with portable MvvmLight, or I possibile to install the not portable version of MvvmLight in the client App?

thanks,
    Luca

Answer (score 0):

The EventToCommand that you're using in `WP8` is not availble on `Windows Store Apps`,

1. If you're working on a `Windows8` app, than [WinRTBehaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) will help you use all behaviors that do what you want (they can help only for Windows8.0 apps (the library is deprecated)).
2. If you are building for `Windows8.1` than download [Behaviors (XAML) SDK for VisualStudio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn457340.aspx) they have InvokeCommandAction which does pretty the same thing